# C...better way of inserting in a string?

Tags: c, string, string-formatting

I want to insert an variable string into a pre-determined string....here is a simplified version of what I have so far (I have omitted error checking etc):

```
void insertPath(char *path)
{
    char *cmd;
    cmd = (char *)malloc(50);
    strcpy(cmd, "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE temp.tablename USING CSVFILE(");

    int new_size = (strlen(cmd) + strlen(path) + 2);
    cmd = (char *)realloc(cmd, new_size);

    strcat(cmd, path);
    strcat(cmd, ");");

   // Do other stuff here and finally free(cmd);



}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

It would be nice to not have to use `malloc` `realloc`, but I do not want to instantiate the `cmd` variable with a fixed length.

(Initially I thought I could do that, then realloc..i.e. `char cmd[50] = "CREATE... "` or `char *cmd = "CREATE..."`, but the `realloc` only works on variables that have been previously `malloc`'d)

The only other way I can think of (and I'm not sure this works) would be:

```
void insertPath(char *path)
{
    char *cmd;
    cmd = (char *)malloc(55);
    strcpy(cmd, "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE temp.tablename USING CSVFILE( %s);");

    int new_size = (strlen(cmd) + strlen(path));
    cmd = (char *)realloc(cmd, new_size);

    sprintf(cmd, path);

   // Do other stuff here and finally free(cmd);
}
```

Comment: "It would be nice to not have to use malloc realloc". Encapsulate them.

Comment: The only way you can think of to do what?  And more generally, what is your question?

Comment: my question is right there... "Is there a better way to do this?". I've given my two attempts at inserting an unknown string into a known one. I'm asking which one (or a 3rd I dont know) is the best way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not forget about `malloc` and thus avoid the memory leak in your code?

i.e

```
size_t len = 55 + strlen(path);
char cmd[len];
```

Then use

```
snprintf(cmd, len, "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE temp.tablename USING CSVFILE(%s);", path);
```

Comment: is `PATH_MAX` a standard or something I need to define?

Comment: It is in `limits.h`. #include lthat

Comment: Also please check if the 50 is sufficent

Comment: As the OP stands this is not a requirement

Comment: I think I'll go with this as I have no need to persist the variable after the function returns...thanks

Comment: well, no 50 is not sufficient, but 55 is.

Comment: Replace PATH_MAX with `strlen(path)` and 50 with 55

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** (in response to comments): `sizeof(char) => 1`, +1 for terminating `\0`

How about `snprintf`?

```
size_t size = baseSize + strlen(path) + 1;
char *cmd = malloc(size);
snprintf(cmd, size, "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE temp.tablename USING CSVFILE(%s);", path);
```

Here, `baseSize` is the length of the "pre-determined" string and `path` is the variable string that you get as an argument in your function. At the end, `cmd` should contain the pre-determined text with the path in place of `%s`.

Comment: sizeof(char) = 1 by standard

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with

```c
void insertPath(char *path)
{
  const char cmd[] = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE temp.tablename USING CSVFILE( %s);";
  int size = strlen(cmd) + strlen(path) + 1; // *sizeof(char) if it makes you happy
  char *newcmd = malloc( size );
  snprintf(newcmd, size, cmd, path);    
}
```

Comment: Nothing. It is almost an exact copy of my answer, but more condescending and without the explanation.

Comment: Also, you can make `cmd` `static`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist it seems we posted about the same time.

Comment: True. I think we all did :)

Comment: By the way, you don't need the +1 in malloc since %s already accounts for two extra characters.

Comment: I'm just keeping my hand in - the last real C program I wrote was in 2005 :P.

Answer (score 0):

Why not?:

```
void insertPath(char *path) {
    char const *tmp = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE temp.tablename USING CSVFILE(";
    char       *cmd = (char*) malloc(strlen(path) + strlen(tmp) + 3);
    strcpy(cmd, tmp);
    strcat(cmd, path);
    strcat(cmd, ");");
}
```

Comment: Better to declare `tmp` as either `const char *` or `char[]`.  Some compilers will in fact tell you so by emitting a warning.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. Also, better yet to make it static.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the unwisdom of creating unsanitized SQL statments by hand, you can use the `sprintf` function, but properly. The arguments are `output`, `format`, `args`. For example:

```
char *insertPath(const char *path)
{
    static const char *cmd = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE temp.tablename USING CSVFILE(%s);";
    char *output = malloc(strlen(cmd) + strlen(path)); // Strictly this should be ... - 1 since it includes the the length of '%s'
    sprintf(output, cmd, path);
    return output;
}
```

Try to avoid allocating memory without need. Here, the template string `cmd` is never modified, so it can be declared `static` and `const`. The output buffer is guaranteed to be long enough if you just add the lengths of the two strings together. Also, remember that if you need to use the value of the new string outside the function, you will have to return the pointer somehow. In your example you call `realloc`, but never let the caller know that the memory block changed. This will often lead to a segfault because `realloc` may or may not change the location of the memory when it expands it.

Comment: I already implicitly have a +2 because the `%s` disappears in the final result.